# QtCreator is missing iOS simulator and kit

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, qt

I have installed Xcode 9.2 and Xconde commandlinetools and everything works ok with them. I could create an iOS application and use simulator to run them.

But now I have installed Qt 5.11 and all the required features for iOS are installed during installation process. Now that I have run QtCreator I can't find iOS kit and also no simulator device is available to be added.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: 1. Is your kit for Xcode configured correct 2. try to start simulator from Xcode first time while Creator open?

Comment: @MohammadKanan, Yeah. Tried all of them